# Reading a text file to a string ALWAYS results in empty string?

Tags: java, text-files, command-line-arguments

For the record, I know that reading the text file to a string does not ALWAYS result in an empty string, but in my situation, I can't get it to do anything else.

I'm currently trying to write a program that reads text from a .txt file, manipulates it based on certain arguments, and then saves the text back into the document. No matter how many different ways I've tried, I can't seem to actually get text from .txt file. The string just returns as an empty string.

For example, I pass in the arguments "-c 3 file1.txt" and parse the arguments for the file (the file is always passed in last). I get the file with:

```
            File inputFile = new File(args[args.length - 1]);
```

When I debug the code, it seems to recognize the file as file1.txt and if I pass in the name of a different file, which doesn't exist, and error is thrown. So it is correctly recognizing this file. From here I have attempted every type of file text parsing I can find online, from old Java version techniques up to Java 8 techniques. None have worked. A few I've tried are:

```
String fileText = "";
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                fileText = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println(fileText);
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            usage();
        }
```

or

```
String fileText = null;
    try {
        fileText = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've tried others too. Buffered readers, scanners, etc. I've tried recompiling the project, I've tried 3rd party libraries. Still just getting an empty string. I'm thinking it must be some sort of configuration issue, but I am stumped.

For anyone wondering, the file seems to be in the correct place, when I reference the wrong location an exception is thrown. And the file DOES in fact have text in it. I've quadruple checked.

Comment: i've copied and pasted your exact code and provided the absolute path to a file on my desktop called file1.txt and i can read the file just fine and output each line of the file. what kind of information is on your file1.txt? try doing the same, create a file on your desktop, add some random info to it, then use the absolute path when creating the file object instead of using the args, as a base test of functionality.

Comment: When you say `fileText = input.nextLine();` the output will be the last line of your input. Instead of it you should use for example `StringBuilder#append`

Comment: So when I read the absolute path, it seems to work. I moved the folder the file to a different location (I had it in the same folder as the Main.java class that I was running, but read that it should be in the project folder outside the src folder), it would read from command line, but only a seemingly random string. Different everytime:

jmpixbx
ycyjqnk
lorkzdz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your first code snippet might read the file, it does in fact not store the contents of the file in your `fileText` variable but **only** the file's last line.
With

```
fileText = input.nextLine();
```

you set `fileText` to the contents of the **current line** thereby overwriting the previous value of `fileText`. You need to store **all** the lines from your file. E.g. try

```
static String read( String path ) throws IOException {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
      sb.append(line).append('\n');
    }
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a method for reading the file into a string which throws an exception with a descriptive message whenever an unexpected state is found. Here is a possible implementation of this idea:

```
public static String readFile(Path path) {
    String fileText;
    try {
        if(Files.size(path) == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("File has zero bytes");
        }
        fileText = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        if(fileText.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("File contains only whitespace");
        }
        return fileText;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This method checks 3 anomalies:

1. File not found
2. File empty
3. File contains only spaces